# to which = where?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if "to which" can be replaced by the word "where".

Here is my question. Please help me.
He went to the shop in which his dad works. 
= He went to the shop where his dad works.

The sentence is correct, but how about the following sentence?

His dad works in the shop to which he went.
= His dad works in the shop where he went.
Is it correct? Or should I say,
"His dad works in the shop where he went to."?

Comment: _The shop where he went_ is OK, or you can retain the unnecessary preposition and leave off the relative pronoun: _the shop he went to_. But _the shop where he went to_ is too much.

Comment: Sometimes it can. But *to which* cannot always be replaced by *where*. For example, *the churches to which Paul wrote* is not the same as *the churches where Paul wrote.*

Comment: @PeterShor Hm, how about *the churches where Paul sent his letters*? Still ambiguous I think.

Answer (score 1):

***[Where](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/where)*** *is also a relative pronoun:*

> *...available at the travel agency where you book your holiday.
>   Wanchai boasts the Academy of Performing Arts, where everything from Chinese Opera to Shakespeare is performed.*

(Collins)

Comment: Actually, "where" is a relative **adverb**.

Comment: @BillJ  both Collins and Cambridge dictionaries define the above usage as a relative pronoun, https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/grammatica-britannico/question-words/where - as well as other dictionaries.

Comment: They are wrong! It has a preposition meaning "in/at/to some place", so there is no logical reason to call it a pronoun. The Oxford gets it right. See here: [link](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/where).

Comment: @BillJ - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133792/is-where-a-relative-pronoun-or-a-relative-adverb

Comment: Swan is wrong, but then by his own admission he is not a qualified grammarian. See the link to the Oxford dictionary that I gave you.

Comment: @BillJ - there is more evidence in favor of being a pronoun  in this case than an adverb, sorry.

Comment: @user067531 BillJ is right: **Here, there** and **where** are all adverbs --**Here** = *at **this** point in time/place*,etc. It is locative, i.e. it expresses “place”. -- **There** *at **that** point in time/space*, etc. It is locative, i.e. it expresses “place”; == And **where** *at,**which** point in time/space*, etc.  It is locative, i.e. it expresses “place”.

Comment: @Greybeard - Collins  appears to disagree.

Comment: @user067531 You have used the wrong verb - "to appear". In fact Collins does disagree and is wrong. The Oxford English Dictionary is far more authoritative; far better researched than Collins, and is clear that "where" is an adverb. 1. If "where" were a pronoun, it would have a referent - it doesn't. 2. if (a) "in which" (preposition + substantive) is an adverbial phrase, and (b) **where** can substitute for ***in* which**, what does that make "where"?

Comment: @Greybeard - Collins is an unreliable source? I’d not say so, sorry. Don’t know on what grounds you say that. I comfortably stick to their definition of where as a pronoun in the examples  they make.

Comment: @user067531 "*Collins is an unreliable source?*" Of course, I did not say that. I said that the OED is far more reliable. -- "*I’d not say so, sorry*." I gladly accept your apologies; you would do well to accept the OED. *"Don’t know on what grounds you say that*. My grounds are given in my comment above at (1) and (2).